# Wie sagt man "to restring" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

> Die Saiten meiner Gitarren sind alt und müssen aufgezogen werden.

Es gibt hier ein weiteres Verb mit demselben Sinn von "to restring", was "neu besaiten" ist.

> Meine Gitarrensaiten müssen nach jedem Konzert besaitet werden.

Ich weiß nicht, welches Verb hier das richtige ist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Gitarre muss neu besaitet werden, nicht die Saiten selbst. Im ersten Satz fehlt das "neu":

> Die Saiten meiner Gitarren sind alt und müssen **neu** aufgezogen werden.

Ohne *neu* vermutet man, dass das Instrument gar keine Saiten hat, bislang, bzw. dass aus irgendeinem Grund die alten Saiten erneut aufgezogen werden sollen (Kein Geld für neue vorhanden oder die neuen sind ein Fehlkauf - vielleicht Klaviersaiten).

Answer (score 7):

Man würde auch sagen

> Meine Gitarre muss nach jedem Konzert neu besaitet werden.

oder

> Ich muss nach jedem Konzert neue Saiten auf meine Gitarre aufziehen.

Aber *nicht*:

> Meine Gitarrensaiten müssen nach jedem Konzert besaitet werden.

Man besaitet ein Instrument, nicht dessen Saiten.

Answer (score 2):

User unknown hat recht, dass [das Wort *neu* fehlt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9974/1224). Aber der Satz

> Die Saiten meiner Gitarre sind alt und müssen neu aufgezogen werden.

ergibt eigentlich keinen Sinn. "Eigentlich" deswegen, weil es trotzdem jeder versteht, und nur wenn man sich doof stellen will, kann man die Aussage des Satzes missinterpretieren.
Dennoch sollte erwähnt sein, dass der Satz korrekterweise aussagt, dass die alte Saiten erneut aufgezogen werden. Im gegebenen Kontext ergibt das keinen Sinn.

Korrekterweise müsste man also sagen:

> Die Saiten meiner Gitarre sind alt und müssen durch neue (Saiten) ersetzt werden.
>   Die Saiten meiner Gitarre sind alt und ich muss neue (Saiten) aufziehen.
>   Die Saiten meiner Gitarre sind alt und die Gitarre muss neu besaitet werden.
>   Die Besaitung meiner Gitarre ist veraltet und muss ersetzt[*or* erneuert] werden.

Der zweite Satz (*Meine Gitarrensaiten müssen nach jedem Konzert besaitet werden.*) ist inhaltlich auch falsch. Wie schon in der [Antwort von Thorsten Dittmar](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9984/1224) erwähnt, werden Gitarrensaiten nicht besaitet. Die Gitarre wird besaitet – und zwar indem man neue Saiten aufzieht. Auch die anderen Beispielsätze in seiner Antwort sind semantisch korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Am Rande: Wäre es keine Gitarre, sondern ein Badmintonschläger, würde man auch von **bespannen** sprechen.

Das nur, weil der englische Begriff ja nicht nur für Musikinstrumente Verwendung findet.